# Django/RapidSMS Foreignkey not a column in table

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, sqlite

so I'm working with RapidSMS which builds on Django and I'm trying to sort of combine their tutorials specifically the [poll app in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/) and the[voting app in rapidsms](http://rapidsms.org/en/develop/tutorial/tutorial03.html#tutorial03) I started with voting and was trying to expand it using code from the django tutorial when I ran into trouble.
(I'm using python27 on a Windows7 64bit, Django 1.5, and SQLite3) Here's what I have in voting.models

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone   
# Create your models here.

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):  
        return self.question
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The poll part shows up fine on admin, I can the question and date, but when I try to add a choice, or touch choices at all I get the error "table voting_choice has no column named poll_id"

I added poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll) after I had made a table for Choice, which I thought might be the problem after some research (maybe it still is) I got the impression that the tables weren't being written over.  So this is what I did :

```
>manage.py sqlclear voting
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE "voting_choice";
DROP TABLE "voting_poll";

COMMIT;

>manage.py sql voting
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "voting_poll" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "question" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "pub_date" datetime NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "voting_choice" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "poll_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "voting_poll" ("id"),
    "name" varchar(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "votes" integer NOT NULL
)
;

COMMIT;
```

So it /says/ that it has that column here. I then syncdb, migrate for good measure and runserver, or the shell and either way entering a poll question/date is fine, but once I try to add a choice or look at a created poll, I get the above mentioned error.
Voting is definitely included in INSTALLED_APPS. So being a Django newbie, I'm lost. If anyone has more suggestions to try they would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Lizzy

Answer (score 1):

What `manage.py sql voting` says is the SQL that wold be generated if Django was going to create the tables. It does not output the current state of the tables nor does it apply the SQL that it outputs. Likewise `manage.py sqlclear voting` shows the SQL to clear the tables but does not apply it to the database.

> I added poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll) after I had made a table for Choice...

There is your problem. `syncdb` does not alter existing tables. You need to either alter the table yourself or drop and have Django recreate it (if you don't have any data worth keeping).